# Extract middle name using SSIS derived column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, derived-column

**(SSIS topic)** I have a Full Name column containing **names with middle initial** and **names without middle initial**. How can i get the middle initial and put it in the Middle Initial column. How can I solve this using **SSIS derived column**.

```
|Middle Initial  |Full Name         |
|                |Carl T. Simpson   |
|                |Karen Thompson    |
|                |Donald J. Clinton |
|                |Samantha Shelby   |
```

This is the outcome that i want to achieve.

```
|Middle Initial      |Full Name         |
|T.                  |Carl T. Simpson   |
|                    |Karen Thompson    |
|J.                  |Donald J. Clinton |
|                    |Samantha Shelby   |
```

Comment: Try this answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de0509a0-d27a-4d1a-bedf-02691ce6159d/separate-first-name-mid-name-and-last-name-in-ssis-expression?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: @Benzi I tried those codes before I post this question, I doesn't work because the column contains names w/ and w/o middle name. If this question is easy its probably answered correctly by now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply solve this problem using the following expression:

```
TOKENCOUNT(@[Full Name]," ") > 2 ? TOKEN(@[Full Name]," ",2) : ""
```

If you are using a previous version of SQL Server 2012, you can try this expression (not sure if it will work for if the middle name is not included):

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@[Full Name],FINDSTRING(@[Full Name]," ",1),FINDSTRING(@[Full Name]," ",2) - FINDSTRING(@[Full Name]," ",1))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer